# setting up letsencrypt certificate at AWS EC2 server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm new to VPS and Linux but I'm now at school and for a project need to use GEOlocation with Django so I need to set up a VPS. I did AWS EC2 server and now I need to add SSL certificate as it a requirement to ask the user for GPS permissions and I'm stuck . I followed the instructions on here :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt

I did set up my domain name in GoDaddy and its working.
this is the error I'm getting :

*> Obtaining a new certificate Performing the following challenges:

> http-01 challenge for [my domain] http-01 challenge for [my domain]
>   Waiting for verification... Challenge failed for domain [my domain]
>   Challenge failed for domain [my domain] http-01 challenge for [my
>   domain] http-01 challenge for [my domain] Cleaning up challenges Some
>   challenges have failed.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: [my domain]    Type:   connection    Detail: Fetching
>   http://[my
>   domain]/.well-known/acme-challenge/g-1VnWMVEKIwAeV0AExkr21aWKtOC6tdTMdbFbBisTE:
>   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
>
> Domain: [my domain]    Type:   connection    Detail: Fetching
>   http://[my
>   domain]/.well-known/acme-challenge/uDE6LFBwGINiZmsULN45PxPK_V48w3NCeoVqv4_ylLY:
>   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
>   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
>   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
>   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
>   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.*

can someone suggest what I can try?

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Have you setup Security Group and open port 443 from anywhere?

Comment: I'm using Apache as per amazon example . and yes i did add 443 Security Group: HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
HTTP
TCP
80
::/0
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
8000
0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
8000
::/0
SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS
TCP
443
0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS
TCP
443
::/0

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was my fault in the end because I by mistake did a port forwarding in my domain and not A address =) thank you for the help